# React useEffect inside const function with MobX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, mobx-react

I have some React Redux code written in Typescript that loads some data from my server when a component mounts. That code looks like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { MyAction } from 'my/types/MyAction';

export const useDispatchOnMount = (action: MyAction) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(action);
    }, [dispatch]);
};
```

This is simple enough - it uses the useEffect hook to do what I want. Now I need to convert the code so that it uses MobX instead of Redux for persistent state. If I have my own MobX store object called myStore, and myStore has a async method "loadXYZ" that loads a specific set of data XYZ, I know I can do this inside my component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async functon doLoadXYZ() {
        await myStore.loadXYZ();
    }
    doLoadXYZ();
}, []);
```

This does indeed work, but I would like to put all this into a single fat arrow function that calls useEffect, much like what the useDispatchOnMount function does. I can't figure out the best way to do this. Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: After further digging, it looks more and more like what I am trying to do with the Mobx version would break the rules of Hooks, ie always call useEffect from the top level of the functional component. So calling it explicitly like this:

```
export const MyContainer: React.FC = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        async functon doLoadXYZ() {
            await myStore.loadXYZ();
        }
        doLoadXYZ();
    }, []);
    ...
};
```

is apparently the best way to go. Butthat raises the question: is the redux version that uses useDispatchOnMount a bad idea? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you don't use async/await in the useEffect. If you are fetching data, I would store it in `myStore` and use it directly out of the store instead of using async/await. It might look something like this:

```
export const SomeComp = observer(function SomeComp() {
  const myStore = useStore() // get the store with a hook or how you are getting it
  useEffect(myStore.loadXYZ, [myStore])

  return <div>{myStore.theLoadedData}</div>
})
```

In `loadXYZ` you just store the data the way you want and use it. The component observing `theLoadedData` will re-render when it comes back so you don't need to have async/await in the component.

Comment: Using async/await in useEffect isn't a problem other than you have to declare that local  function doLoadXYZ as in my example. Otherwise, you code is basically the same as mine where I call useEffect from the top level of the component.  I already know that works. I am just wondering if you can call useEffect from within a const function, much like what useDispatchOnMount does.

Comment: Also, I have a class MyStore that I declare somewhere (say path/to/my/store/MyStore) and that file exports a variable myStore that is an instance of MyStore. Can't I just import { myStore } from 'path/to/my/store/MyStore'; ? It isn't clear to me why I need to call useStore(). And how would useStore() know to get that instance myStore from 'path/to/my/store/MyStore?